# Failed to get Control-M definition from the GUI server for the following server

Tags: control-m

When I check in a developed Control-M draft in Control-M version 9.0.19.200, I am getting the following error:

> Failed to get Control-M definition from the GUI server for the following server: <DATACENTER>.

Could anyone please help me how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause for this issue was:

1. DATACENTER hostname is provided in UPPERCASE instead of lowercase.
2. DATACENTER hostname got changed to another host due to the Control-M platform migration.